# How to embed facebook video?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know how to embed a facebook video?

I followed instructions at:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player

But it does not work. This is the source code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <h1>My Video Player</h1>
    <div class="fb-video"
    data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/posts/10151471074398553"
    data-width="500"
    data-allowfullscreen="true"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old post. But this code is the answer. For more information [look here.](https://www.facebook.com/help/1570724596499071?helpref=uf_permalink)

```html
<!-- replace {facebook-video-url} with the correct url-->
<iframe 
  src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href={facebook-video-url}&show_text=0&width=560"
  width="560" height="315" 
  style="border:none;overflow:hidden" 
  scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"
></iframe>
<!--example given-->
<iframe 
  src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FPlayStation%2Fvideos%2F10155554431506803%2F&show_text=0&width=560"
  width="560" height="315" 
  style="border:none;overflow:hidden" 
  scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"
></iframe>
```

Comment: Perfect solution!

Answer (score 2):

When you press recieve code , Click the tab for the Iframe. This works better for me

It would look something like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook%2Fvideos%2F10153231379946729%2F&width=500&show_text=false&height=281&appId" 
        width="500" height="281" 
        style="border:none;overflow:hidden" 
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"
></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe 
  src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FPlayStation%2Fvideos%2F10155554431506803%2F&show_text=0&width=560"                                                           
  width="560" height="315" 
  style="border:none;overflow:hidden" 
  scrolling="no" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"
></iframe>
```

This works for me.